# webapi controller calling wrong method

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented a generic controller using c# and webApi 2.0

http://localhost:4200/api/projects
will correctly call GetAllItems()  and return the expected results

http://localhost:4200/api/projects/1
does not call GetItemById( )
Instead, it calls GetAllItems( )

prior to building the generic, i built a concrete controller for projects.
Its a cut/paste and it calls the correct methods.
My thinking is that my route is wrong on the generic, or should be different because it is a generic, but I can not seem to come up w/ the correct syntax.

**Why is the generic not calling the correct method when the url includes a trailing integer?**

### Things i tried w.o success

Reordering the methods

Enhancing the verb to be System.Web.Http.HttpGet

Combining GET and ROUTE into 1 tag, comma separated

Specifying  [FromUri] on the itemId parameter in the function signature

Commenting out the GetAllItems() --> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'  (This has to be the big clue, but for the life of me...)

Here is an abbreviated listing of the generic template

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/{contoller}")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class baseController<T, T_Q > : ApiController 
                where T:pgBaseClass, new()
                where T_Q : sbQuery<T> , new()
                 
    {

        

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public CustomJsonStringResult GetAllItems()
        {
            T_Q q = new T_Q();
            List<T> l = q.Items();


            string json = q.ListToJSON(l);

            return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, json, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{itemId:int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetItemById(int itemId)
        {
            T_Q q = new T_Q();
            T p = q.GetById(itemId);

            if (p == null)
            {
                return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, "Item not Found", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, p.JSON, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the definition for the projects controller using the generic

```
  public class ProjectsController : baseController<pgProject,pgProjectQuery>
    {
  }
```

Here is an abbreviated listing of the non generic  controller that works as expected.
(I am excluding one or the other to get the project to compile and run...)

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/projects")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class  ProjectController : ApiController
    {

        //[HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public CustomJsonStringResult GetAllItems()
        {
            pgProjectQuery ag = new pgProjectQuery();
            ag.SortExpression = " [Name] asc ";
            List<pgProject> l = ag.Items();


            string json = ag.ListToJSON(l);

            return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, json, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{itemId:int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetItemById(int itemId)
        {
            pgProjectQuery q = new pgProjectQuery();
            pgProject p = q.GetById(itemId);
            
            if (p == null)
            {
                return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, "Item not Found", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, p.JSON, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this configured in webApiConfig.js

here i have the sole route defined w/ an optional parameter called id.
I changed the parameter name in my GetItemById() method and this works.

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
// Web API configuration and services

```
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.EnableCors();
    
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

}


  [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:int}")]
        public CustomJsonStringResult GetItemById([FromUri] int id){...}
```

What I can not explain is why the non generic controller worked as expected but the generic-based controller does not.
I do believe things are probably 'more correct' now, just wish I had a factual answer.
I also ran into the same problem with my patch method. Renamed the parameter to id and it worked.

Hope this helps someone down the line.