# Can Derivatives of a Generic Controller define routes

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have defined a generic controller and have a couple derived classes  that are working.

This is fabulous.

I  now run into the case where I want to add a route to one of the concrete derivations.

It does not seem to want to pick up the new routes. Error messages tell me that it is looking at the right class.

I have defined the generic and a derived class here.

[webapi controller calling wrong method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538949/webapi-controller-calling-wrong-method)

I am  about to throw in the towel on this exercise.

**Is is possible for the derived classes to add routes?  Does anyone know of examples  (i know, i cant ask for examples...)**

Thanks

paratial listing of the generic
GetItemById() works if I uncomment it

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/{contoller}")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class baseController<T, T_Q, M> : ApiController
                where T : pgBaseClass, new()
                where T_Q : sbQuery<T>, new()
                where M : new()
    {


        //[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        //[Route("{id}")]
        //public CustomJsonStringResult GetItemById([FromUri] string id)
        //{
        //    T_Q q = new T_Q();
            
        //    T p = q.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(id));

        //    if (p == null)
        //    {
        //        return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, "Item not Found", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, p.JSON, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        //    }
        //}


       

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public CustomJsonStringResult GetAllItems()
        {
            T_Q q = new T_Q();
            List<T> l = q.Items();


            string json = q.ListToJSON(l);

            return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, json, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
}
```

partial listing of one concrete class

```
     public class ProjectsController : baseController<pgProject,pgProjectQuery, Models.mpgProject>
    {

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}/cfs")]
        public CustomJsonStringResult GetCashFlows([FromUri] string id)
        {


            pgCashFlowQuery q = new pgCashFlowQuery();
            pgCashFlow p = q.GetById( Convert.ToInt32(id ));

            if (p == null)
            {
                return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, "Item not Found", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                List<pgCashFlowString> l = p.CashFlowStrings;
                pgCashFlowStringQuery q2 = new pgCashFlowStringQuery();
                string json = q2.ListToJSON(l);
                return JSONStringResultExtension.JSONString(this, p.JSON, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

        }
}
```

full listing of webApiCOnfig.cs w/ 1 route hard coded

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                            name: "Collection",
                            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/cfs",
                            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                        );
        }
    }
```

When I call the api w/

```
http://localhost:4200/api/projects/3
```

I will get the json i expect (except i have it commented out here..)

same for `http://localhost:4200/api/projects`
I get the list.

now when I call `http://localhost:4200/api/projects/3/cfs`
the GetAllItems() method is triggered.

This is exactly the example posted by MS at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing
where they have

```
[Route("{id:int}/details")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(BookDetailDto))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBookDetail(int id)
```

describing the method that will return details for a book.

### Things I have tried

- Changing {id:int} to {id} and changing the method parameter to string. This seems to be more of a complicating factor than i want it to be. I am likely conflating this with something else I have yet to understand.
- commenting out the hardcoded route.  WHen I do this , and during other experiments I get "ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure".   The peculiar thing here is that all articles i read about  this talk about .NetCore.  This projechappens to be .Net Framework 4.7.2..

The WEB tab on PROPERTIES shows I am launching IIS Express using default bitness.
I really do not see anything that would bring .NetCore into this equation

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Show us some example code so we can actually help though.

Comment: Have you tried using [Route("something/other")] and if so, what errors are you seeing

Comment: thanks for the time gents. I have added code as well as a couple things I have tried so far.